# JQuery, Call Action and return View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I'have a dialog box in JQuery that have two buttons. When the button "Upload Anyway" is clicked I call an Action of my Controller.
    $(function () {
    $("#dialog:ui-dialog").dialog("destroy");

```
$("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
    resizable: false,
    height: 300,
    width: 500,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Upload Anyway": function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
            var month = '@ViewBag.duplicateString' ;
            var path = $("#path").val();
           $.getJSON('@Url.Action("UpdateComp")', { dateToUpdate: month, filePath: path }, 
            function()   {});
        },
        Cancel: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
```

In the Controller I just want to process the data and return a view.

```
    public ActionResult UpdateComp (string dateToUpdate, string filePath)
    {
        //Process Data
        return View(compList.Values.AsEnumerable<CompUser>());
    }
```

When I click over the "Upload Anyway" I'm correctly redirected to the Action (I've checked with debug), but the view is not loaded. I'm not very good at JQuery so maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the $.getJSON by $.get and display the resulted view in my main div solve the problem.

Note that I render a partial view in order to display the div correctly.

Here is the JQuery code, hope that will help some other person.

```
$(function () {
$("#dialog:ui-dialog").dialog("destroy");
$("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
    resizable: false,
    height: 300,
    width: 500,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Upload Anyway": function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
            var month = '@ViewBag.duplicateString' ;
            var path = $("#path").val();
            $.get('@Url.Action("UpdateComp")', { dateToUpdate: month, filePath: path }, function(result) {
                $('#main_div').html(result);
            })
                .error(function() { alert("A Problem occurs during the comparison"); });
        },
        Cancel: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Sorry for not responding to your comments. You implemented my answer and marked your response as the answer...

Answer (score 0):

Your callback on $.getJSON is doing nothing. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ and look at the "success" parameter.

But, if you're returning a View (HTML, etc), then you're not "getting JSON", you're getting HTML. Try using [$.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) or [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) (depending on requirement) instead and displaying the returned view to the user in your success callback.

Comment: If I understand you well, I have to call my View in the JQuery success function. If it's so I've no idea how to di this and most of all how to give the model to the view in Jquery???

Comment: I've tried with $.get and $.post but nothing append either. I really don't understand why it don't redirect me to my view...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var url = '@Url.Action("method_name", "controller_name")?dateToUpdate=' + month + '&filePath=' + path;
window.location.href = url;
```